# jqplot bars not lining up with grid

Tags: javascript, canvas, jqplot

Does anyone know why *some* of the bars are not lining up in this jqplot bar graph?  You can find this at http://www.vonlay.com/jollymeter/app

[image: Bar not lining up with the grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, my y-axis format string was masking the fact that the grid lines weren't on integer values.

```
yaxis: { min: 0, tickOptions: { formatString: "%d" } }
```

[This topic](http://groups.google.com/group/jqplot-users/browse_thread/thread/c99850b3e562256c) talks about what I was trying to achieve and the issue that I had unintentionally caused.

[image: Plot with y-axis format string removed]